# How to copy an instance of Aurora DB to another existing instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, copy, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I've tried searching for this but most articles point to cloning which creates a new DB.
I have a DEV1 and a DEV2 aurora db setup.
We've made several changes to our database structure and I'd like to copy the DEV1 database and overwrite the DEV2 database.
I can take a snapshot of DEV1, but it won't let me restore it into DEV2 as it seems it wants to create a whole new cluster instead. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Another related question: what is the best way to keep database structures in sync between two DBs as we develop?

Comment: Depending on the database technology, is there a reason you can't do this with the native tools for the underlying databases e.g `mysqldump` for mysql or mariadb?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. 
I simply used the workbench to copy the structure. 
Also found a great way to kid large data sets into Aurora using “Load from S3” functionality. Brilliant. I still can’t help it think that the console should make something like this available though.

Comment: you can use liquibase for maintaining the DDL deployments.